# How to automatically include the current year for my copyright message using Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How do I display the current year in the page footer like `©year` in Vue.js? Eg. "©2021" or "©2020".

The following is the pure JavaScript version:

```js
document.write(new Date().getFullYear())
```

In pure JavaScript, I have to manually inject the year into the document somewhere– how can I do this automatically with Vue instead?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Why not just use [text interpolation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Text)?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
©{{ new Date().getFullYear() }}
</div>
```

Comment: is there any short way of doing this something like macro or constants?

Answer (score -1):

You can add current year automatically in your web page.

```
<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script>
```

This will works for all browser's

Comment: Yah this is working but i working in vue.js framwork so I wanna do it on it, I got the answer Thank you